# Where is the documentation for javascript for the pnp libraries?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin, typescript

I am trying to build a SharePoint Add-In and I am struggling because all documentation seems to be in TypeScript. I am sure TS is great but I don't have time to learn it right now. Does MSFT not have docs in javascript?

https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/docs/items/

Answer (score 2):

All of the PnP JavaScript libraries are written in TypeScript.  As such, there are no exemplar JavaScript files.

All of the tooling to implement customizations in SharePoint has changed.  e.g.: SP Designer —> Gulp, Yeoman, Node, etc.
This is a major hurdle that I and other DevOps have had to overcome (in my case, I still am).

Comment: I looked into Yeoman and there is no choice for Add-In's and I need to make an Add-In. What am I supposed to use to generate the project files? There is no documentation on how I should use Node and Gulp for a SharePoint Add-In.

Comment: Also, I have never used SP Designer. I am accustomed to using Visual Studio 2017 as an IDE.

Answer (score 1):

You will be surprised, but below is a valid javascript:

```
// get all the items from a list
sp.web.lists.getByTitle("My List").items.get().then(items => {
    console.log(items);
});
```

It works in all modern browsers.  You see, it doesn't differ significantly from the samples for PnPjs. In most cases, it requires an additional tool, which transforms this code into a module (tools like Babel or Typescript compiler). Today you simply can't create a big scalable solution in Javascript without modularity.
I recommend you to spend some time and dig into modern JavaScript (or Typescript it even better)

Comment: What is the shortest route to getting a dev environment for a SharePoint Add-In that allows me to leverage this new PnP JS set of libraries.

Comment: You can create a project using Visual Studio (SharePoint Add-in template), add pnpjs library file using the same approach as `App.js` inside generated project and basically you're good to go.